# to edit the item which i submit in form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

- I am trying to edit the item which i submit in form fields...
- after i edit it when i submit it its not updating the particular item...
- do you know how to fix it...
- providing code below...

http://codepen.io/gborbonus/pen/grRjjy?editors=1011

```
$('#localStorageTest').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
    var div = "<div><span>"+name+"</span><span >"+email+"</span><span>"+message+"</span><input type='button' value='Edit' name='editHistory'><input type='button' value='Delete' name='deleteHistory'></div>";  //add your data in span, p, input.. 
    //alert(div);

    $('.gettingValues').append(div); //apendd the div
    $('#localStorageTest')[0].reset(); //clear the form 
    localStorage.clear();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..
You should empty the div before appending the content to div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#localStorageTest').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
    var div = "<div><span>"+name+"</span><span >"+email+"</span><span>"+message+"</span><input type='button' value='Edit' name='editHistory'><input type='button' value='Delete' name='deleteHistory'></div>";  //add your data in span, p, input.. 
    //alert(div);

    $('.gettingValues').empty();//clear all the content.

    $('.gettingValues').append(div); //apendd the div
    $('#localStorageTest')[0].reset(); //clear the form 
    localStorage.clear();
 });
```

Comment: but its creating a new bug when i enter multiple values its not showing as list http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONgozX?editors=0011  which was working fine in my previous codepen